# Tengo un problema con programación condicional

Tags: python, condiciones, vscode, else

Soy realmente nuevo en la programación y apenas estoy sentando las bases. Estudio código en python y tengo que hace uno de programación condicional, sobre multiplicar dos números. Si uno de dichos números es menor a cuarenta, se multiplican sin mas, pero si es mayor, uno de ellos se multiplicará antes por 1.5 y luego el resultado por el número mayor a 40.
esto es lo que eh escrito, pero me marca error, a pesar de que ayer escribí algo parecido y me funcionó perfecto

```
    Pay = 0
hrs = input("Ingrese Horas:")
tarifa = input("Ingese Tarifa:")
h = float(hrs)
t = float(tarifa)
if h < 40 :
    (h * t)
    elif h > 40 :
        Pay = ((t*1.5)*h)
        
print(Pay)
```

Mi editor de texto es vscode, por si acaso

Comment: Debo decir que ya logré terminar este código, pero mi duda en si persiste. Termine este usando dos if´s, pero inmediatamente al siguiente me pidió algo similar donde si necesito usar if-else-elif, pero en ninguno de mis códigos funcionan el else/elif. Estoy aprendiendo de un curso, pero ninguno de los códigos del maestro me han servido y el decía que se usaban el else y elif sin más, ya quedó claro que no, asi que cualquier explicación sobre el if, else y elif me sirve bastante por que el curso no ayuda mucho en el tema

Comment: Por favor, lee [ask]. Pon en el título cuál es realmente el problema. Además, ¿estás seguro/a que está bien indentado tu código? Tal como está tu pregunta, pareciera ser que no. Recuerda siempre que en Python la indentación es _crítica_. Y no es que el curso no ayude, tal como estás comentando/describiendo y por cómo se ve, el error está en tu código, no en la enseñanza...

Comment: Bueno, claro que el error está en mi código, por eso pregunto en esta web si alguien me explica como solucionarlo, por que la explicación que me dan es bastante vaga o a veces no resuelve problemas bastante específicos que me suceden

Answer (score 0):

Tienes un pequeño error en tu código. La palabra clave `elif` se usa para expresar una condición alternativa después de un `if`, pero estás usando `elif` inmediatamente después de un `if`, lo cual es incorrecto. Debes usar `elif` después de un `if` para expresar una segunda condición si la primera no es verdadera. Además, no estás calculando el salario correctamente dentro de tu condición.

```
Pay = 0
hrs = input("Ingrese Horas:")
tarifa = input("Ingese Tarifa:")
h = float(hrs)
t = float(tarifa)

if h < 40:
    Pay = h * t
elif h >= 40:
    Pay = (40 * t) + ((h - 40) * 1.5 * t)

print(Pay)
```

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias por tu ayuda! Aunque no entendí bien la parte de no usar un elif después de un if, ¿entonces que va despues? ¿debo poner un else antes, o como?

(Soy bastante nuevo en esto, comencé la semana pasada. El sujeto que da el curso del que estoy aprendiendo dijo que estaba bien usar elif o else después de if, pero en ninguno de mis códigos está funcionando, y no se porqué. La verdad es que casi ninguno de sus códigos me funciona y debo modificarlos todos yo, asi que ya no creo mucho si realmente funcione su programación)

Answer (score 0):

Mas que los errores de tu codigo, por tus comentarios creo que el problema es que o no te han explicado o no has entendido algunos conceptos basico de Python como son los bloques de codigo y la importancia de la identacion. Hay varios conceptos básicos de aburrida sintaxis que debes entender antes de nada:

### Sentencias (staments)

Podemos definir las sentencias como las unidades básicas de instrucción que el intérprete de Python analiza y procesa:

```
a = 8            # Una sentencia
b = 2            # Otra sentencia
print(a + b)     # Otra sentencia
```

En general, el intérprete ejecuta las sentencias una tras otra a medida que las encuentra, secuencialmente, pero esto se puede modificar como veremos. Por norma general, cada secuencia esta definida en una linea y termina por un salto de linea.

### Sentencias compuestas

Básicamente son sentencias que **contienen** grupos de otras sentencias, permitiendo influenciar, controlar o condicionar su ejecución. `if-else-elif`, `while` y `for`, `try-except-finally-else`, `def`, `class`, etc, permiten definir sentencias compuestas.

Una sentencia compuesta puede tener una o mas clausulas, cada clausula tiene un encabezado que termina en `:` y un "cuerpo" que constituye el bloque de sentencias afectado por ese encabezado:

```
encabezado 1:  | Clausula 1
    bloque 1   |

encabezado 2:  | Clausula 2
    bloque 2   |
...
```

**Los encabezados de las clausulas de una misma sentencia compuesta tienen que tener el mismo nivel de identación. El cuerpo o bloque de sentencias que forma parte de cada clausula debe tener un nivel mas de sangrado que su encabezado.**

### Bloques de código

Podemos definir un bloque de código como un conjunto de sentencias que son tratadas como una única sentencia y ejecutadas como una unidad. Obviamente se necesita de algo para indicar cuando comienza y cuando termina un bloque de código en el texto que conforma el programa. Muchos lenguajes recurren a usar llaves, o palabras especiales como `begin-end` para delimitar bloques:

```
if condicion {  | La llave de apertura indica que se inicia un bloque
    a = "foo"   | 
    b = 7       |
    c = b * 13  |
}               | La llave de cierre indica que termina un bloque 

c = "Hola"      | Fuera de las llaves, por lo que no forma parte del bloque
```

Python usa la identacion/sangrado para definir que sentencias forman parte de un mismo bloque de código. Lo hace deliberadamente para forzar al programador a escribir código legible correctamente sangrado.

**Las sentencias que forman parte de un mismo bloque de código deben estar identadas/sangradas al mismo nivel.**

```
if condicion:
    a = "foo"   | Estas tres sentencias forma parte del mismo bloque
    b = 7       | Las tres están identadas al mismo nivel
    c = b * 13  | y se ejecutan si se cunple el if

d = "Hola"      | Esta linea tiene un nivel menos de sangrado, no forma parte del bloque. Se evalua despues del if independientemente de este.
```

El sangrado en Python no es solo una buena practica para hacer el código legible, forma parte de la sintaxis del lenguaje ya que cada nivel de identacion define un bloque de codigo distinto.

### if-elif-else

Las palabras `if-elif-else` se pueden usar para construir un bloque condicional y nos permiten controlar el flujo de ejecución, es decir alterar la ejecución secuencial por defecto de las sentencias en fucnion de la evaluacion como verdaderas o no de las expresiones que las acompañan. Dicha sentencia compuesta puede estar formada por una o mas clausulas:

- Sentencia `if`: Inicia la sentencia condicional, por lo que es obligatoria.
- Sentencia `elif`: es opcional, siempre tiene que ir precedida de una clausula `if` o `elif` y pueden definirse el numero que se quiera. Solo se evalúa si tanto el `if` como todos los `elif` anteriores a el no son evaluados como verdaderos.
- Sentencia `else`: es opcional y solo puede haber una por cada `if`, siendo la ultima clausula siempre. Solo se ejecutara si tanto el `if` como todos los posibles `elif` que le preceden se han evaluado como falsos.

Como se dijo antes de forma general, todos los `elif` y el `else` (de existir) que formen parte de un mismo bloque condicional tienen que estar sangrados al mismo nivel que el `if` que lo inicia.

Por lo tanto, una sentencia compuesta  `if-elif-else` empieza siempre con un `if` y termina por una de las siguientes razones:

- No hay mas código en el archivo (obvio...)
- Se define un `else`, que como se ha dicho es la ultima clausula (de existir).
- La identacion indica que termina el bloque condicional. Es decir, hay una sentencia identada al mismo nivel que el `if` y **que no es un `elif` o un `else`**.

Una duda común es plantearse que diferencia hay entre:

```
n = int(input("Ingrese un entero: "))

if n == 0:
    print("Es cero")
elif n == 1:
    print("Es uno")
elif n == 2:
    print("Es dos")
else:
    print("No es cero, ni uno, ni dos")
```

y:

```
n = int(input("Ingrese un entero: "))

if n == 0:
    print("Es cero")
if n == 1:
    print("Es uno")
if n == 2:
    print("Es dos")
if n !=0 and n != 1:
    print("No es cero, ni uno, ni dos")
```

Bien, en cuanto al resultado, en este caso, ninguna. Pero si que hay diferencias:

- Para empezar en el primer caso tenemos una única sentencia compuesta, con una clausula `if`, dos `elif` y una `else`. En el segundo tenemos tres sentencias compuestas, tres bloques condicionales independientes conformados cada uno por una sola sentencia `if`.
- Lo anterior no es trivial. La forma en la que se evalúa y se ejecuta el código es muy diferente:

  - En el primer caso:

    - Si ingresamos un cero, el interprete evalúa el `if`, como se cumple ejecuta el bloque de código de su cuerpo y aquí termina. Los `elif` y el `else` no son evaluados.
    - Si se ingresa un uno, se evalúa el `if`, como es falso se pasa al primer `elif`, como es verdadero, se ejecuta su contenido. El segundo `elif` y `else` de nuevo son ignorados.
    - Si se ingresa un dos, se evalúa el `if` (falso), luego el primer `elif` (falso) y luego el segundo `elif`, que al ser verdadero se ejecuta su cuerpo.
    - Si se ingresa cualquier otra cosa se evalúa el `if` y los dos `elif`, como todos son falsos, se ejecuta el `else`.
  - En el segundo caso, da igual lo que ingresemos, **se evalúan todos los condicionales siempre**, no importa que alguno de los anteriores sea cierto, siempre se van a evaluar los cuatro.

En este caso, el segundo código genera la misma salida, pero es mucho mas ineficiente. Moraleja, si tus condiciones son excluyentes (como en este caso) usa un `if-elif-else` y no `if` encadenados.

### Tu código

```
1.  Pay = 0
2.  hrs = input("Ingrese Horas:")
3.  tarifa = input("Ingese Tarifa:")
4.  h = float(hrs)
5.  t = float(tarifa)
6.  if h < 40 :
7.      (h * t)
8.      elif h > 40 :
9.          Pay = ((t*1.5)*h)
10.        
11. print(Pay)
```

- En la linea 6 inicias un bloque condicional con un `if` que comprueba si `h` es menor que 40. Correcto.
- Si se cumple el `if`, se ejecuta el bloque de código que conforma su cuerpo, en este caso `(h * t)`. En cuanto a sintaxis es correcto, pero hay un problema, esa linea no hace nada, bueno si, es una expresión que multiplica `h` y `t` y genera un objeto `float` como resultado. El problema es que no haces nada con ese `float`, simplemente se pierde (el recolector de basura de Python lo destruye sin compasión mas bien...). Debes asignar el resultado de la expresión a tu variable `Pay`, es decir `Pay = h * t`, para poder luego usar ese `float` referenciandolo con dicha variable, como en `print(Pay)`.
- En la siguiente linea tenemos un `elif h > 40 :`. Aquí el interprete si que se queja... Eso es un error de sintaxis. Ese `elif` forma parte de la expresión compuesta iniciada con la clausula `if`, y recuerda que dijimos que las cabeceras de una misma expresión deben estar identadas al mismo nivel. Es decir, ese `elif` debe tener el mismo nivel de sangrado que el `if`.

  Al darle un nivel mas de sangrado, indicas que forma parte del bloque de código a ejecutar si el `if` se cumple y no una clausula mas del bloque condicional. Al ser tratado como un bloque diferente, el interprete ve que estas usando una sentencia `elif` no precedía de un `if` y llora amargamente porque eso no es correcto como ya explicamos (un `elif` solo puede ir precedido de una sentencia `if` o `elif`, y en este caso va después de `(h * t)`).
- La sentencia `Pay = ((t*1.5)*h)` se debe ejecutar si se cumple el `elif`. Por lo que debe ir "dentro" del mismo, identado un nivel mas que la sentencia `elif`, tal como lo tienes.

Bien, si corregimos lo señalado:

```
pay = 0
hrs = input("Ingrese Horas:")
tarifa = input("Ingese Tarifa:")
h = float(hrs)
t = float(tarifa)

if h < 40:
    pay = h * t
elif h > 40:
    pay = t * 1.5 * h

print(pay)
```

Parece correcto, pero hay un problema de lógica. El interprete de Python es feliz, pero te aseguro que el desgraciado trabajador como trabaje 40 horas exactas... mejor que no sepa donde vives...

Efectivamente, tu condicional deja fuera el caso `h = 40`, ni se cumple el `if` ni el `elif`, resultado `pay = 0`... Debes decidir que pasa con ese 40, por ejemplo incluyéndolo en el `elif` con `elif h >= 40`. Pero en este caso, simplemente no uses un `elif`, usa el `else`, si el `if` no se cumple el `elif` lo hace siempre, no tiene sentido evaluarlo, es gastar electricidad en la CPU para nada:

```
pay = 0
hrs = float(input("Ingrese Horas: "))
tarifa = float(input("Ingese Tarifa: "))

if hrs < 40:
    pay = hrs * tarifa
else:
    pay = hrs * tarifa * 1.5

print(pay)
```

Comment: Wow muchísimas gracias, la verdad lo de los bloques de código si lo entendía, en si conozco bastante las bases de la programación, pero solo la lógica, apenas empiezo a intentar aplicarlo a un código escrito, y ahí se pierde el entenderlo en no saber hacerlo realmente, pero creo que ya entendí